# removing duplicates from list of arrays and concatenating associated values

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

I have two lists of arrays of data (cost and account) identified by the list 'number'.  Each array in the lists are of different lengths, but each cost array has a corresponding account array of the same length.

I would like to remove the duplicates in the list number and concatenate the corresponding data in cost and account together for each duplicate.  The ordering is important.  Here's an example of the lists I have:

```
number = [4, 6, 8, 4, 8]

cost = [array([1,2,3], dtype = uint64), array([5,6,7,8], dtype = uint64), array([9,10,11], dtype= uint64), array([13,14,15], dtype = uint64), array([17,18], dtype = uint64)]

account = [array([.1,.2,.3], dtype = float32), array([.5,.6,.7,.8], dtype = float32), array([.5,.10,.11], dtype= float32), array([.13,.14,.15], dtype = float32), array([32,.18], dtype = float32)]
```

The desired result is to have:

```
number = [4,6,8]
cost = [[1,2,3,13,14,15],[5,4,7,8],[9,10,11,17,18]]
account = [[.1,.2,.3,.13,.14,.15],[.5,.6,.7,.8],[.5,.10,.11,32,.18]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this with indexing or dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

If number order is not important (e.g [8,4,6]), You can do as follows:

```
number = [4, 6, 8, 4, 8]
cost = [[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10,11],[13,14,15],[17,18,19]]
account = [[.1,.2,.3],[.5,.6,.7],[.9,.0,.1],[.3,.4,.5],[.7,.8,.9]]

duplicates = lambda lst, item: [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]
indexes = dict((n, duplicates(number, n)) for n in set(number))

number = list(set(number))
cost = [sum([cost[num] for num in val], []) for valin indexes.values()]
account = [sum([account[num] for num in val], []) for valin indexes.values()]
```

The indexes will be dictionary with number as key and indexes as values using duplicates finder lambda function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please format your code properly, without the use of <br> (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# Find unique values in "number" 
number, idx, inv = np.unique(number,return_index=True,return_inverse=True)
# concatenate "cost" based on unique values
cost = [np.asarray(cost)[np.where(inv==i)[0]].flatten().tolist() \
              for i in idx ]
# concatenate "account" based on unique values
account = [np.asarray(account)[np.where(inv==i)[0]].flatten().tolist() \ 
              for i in idx ]

# Check
In [248]: number
[4 6 8]
In [249]: cost
[[1, 2, 3, 13, 14, 15], [5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 17, 18, 19]]
In [250]: account
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0.5, 0.6, 0.7], [0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]]
```

`np.asarray()` and `tolist()` are unnecessary if your inputs are `numpy` arrays, so you might want to get rid of them. I just added them so that they work for Python lists too.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the MWE to reflect the true problem.  This solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yes it does. The problem is with your data. In your updated question you declare `account` to be made up of `numpy` arrays of unsigned integers (`uint64`), when it actually contains floating point numbers. Change `uint64` to `float64` instead for `account`.